# Hiding an element using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qlayout

I'm trying to hide a QDoubleSpinBox in a Qt interface program, using c++.

I have found the function hide(), but it is not working as I expected, since when I hide the element, the space it used to occupy, is not taken into account, so all my window turns crazy. I was wondering if there is any function to hide and keep the space occupied, like if it is normal. I thought that maybe would be a function like this because is common in other frameworks or even JavaScript.

If there is not... any solution?

Comment: Have a look here, this worked well for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10840906/131930

Comment: in the same post as the one Jeremy provided, there are good alternatives : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10819251/1122645

Comment: Is that really necessary to hide element? That would be quite confusing to user, and you can disable your widgets - this should provide clear statement that user cannot use this element now.

Comment: There is also the `setVisible(0)` method but it will produce the same shifts in layouts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of layouts. Layouts automatically recalculate when you add/remove or show/hide elements. You can just opt to not use layouts.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed that layouts recalculate the space when an object is missing but... is there not any other option?

Comment: If the widget is not in the middle of other widgets, you can use vertical/horizontal spacers to make sure the layout stays the same.

Comment: is this answering the question?

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to try setting the opacity to 0.0 instead of hiding the QDoubleSpinBox.

```
mySpinBox.setWindowOpacity(0.0);
```

Actually I don't think that will work.

The easiest thing I can think of to do, would be to subclass the QDoubleSpinBox, then override the paint function (and probably the mouse handling) to be turned on and off with your own variable.

Comment: The issue is that a paint event is sent to an object only when the object is visible

Comment: Right, but if you control what the paint event does (and if it receives input) from your own input, you could leave the object visible, and simply not display it.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly quick but not elegant solution would be to subclass the desired widget, add in an additional bool to make the widget invisible without removing its geometry and a method to toggle it, and in the overloaded paint event, if the bool is true, call the original paint event from the base class, else don't draw anything. This will result in a totally transparent widget that will still accept events, that is why you can also use `setEnabled()` with the bool to also disable it while it is hidden.

Not very applicable when you want to hide and show many objects, but in the case of one or two it works and is very quick to implement.