# Make a QLabel blink

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

I'm using Qt to make a gui application for my beagleboard.

I'm trying to make a QLabel blink with a custom image.

```
QTimer::connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(blink()));
timer->start(1000);
```

I'm thinking to use QTimer to call the blink() function every second, but I do not have a clue what the code should be in blink() function. I hope someone can help, since i have struggle with this problem in a while now.

Comment: the simplest approach is to use a movie: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlabel.html#setMovie

Answer (score 3):

Create **blinking** animation in a [GIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) file.

Create whatever animation you like with tools like [GIF Animator](https://www.gif-animator.com/).

Show it like below:

```
auto movie = new QMovie("myblinking.gif"); 
QLabel blinklabel = new QLabel();
blinklabel->setMovie(movie);
movie->start();
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to hide and show it again.

```
Class::blink()
{
    if(label->isHidden())
        label->show();
    else
        label->hide();
}
```

This approach is good because you don't need to set your image again and again, just show/hide it(set empty pixmap or set image every second is not efficient approach).

If you use layout, then it can really break your layout, so you can use `QStackedWidget` with imageLabel and empty label and change it every second. I think that it will be still better than set empty pixmap or set image every second. Choose the best for you.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedwidget.html

Comment: Depending on the layout around the QLabel, this code could do more than just a blink: moving other widgets in a unwanted way

Comment: @Antwane Yes, you are right, OP didn't tell about layout but it is really dangerous, so I improved my answer.

Comment: You can do this in one line: `label->setVisible(!label->isVisible());`

Answer (score 0):

Using a bool member `isQLabelVisible` in your class

```
Class::blink() {
    if(isQLabelVisible) {
        doHideQLabel();
        isQLabelVisible = false;
    } else {
        doShowQLabel();
        isQLabelVisible = true;
    }
}

void Class::doHideQLabel() {
    [...]
}

void Class::doShowQLabel() {
    [...]
}
```

You have a starting point for a good solution. Now, to implements `do{Hide,Show}QLabel()`, read answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794532/how-to-make-a-qt-widget-invisible-without-changing-the-position-of-the-other-qt) and decide which one is the best for your needs.