# How to make a QGraphicsView background blinking in R - G - B every second

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qgraphicsview

As the title says I am trying to have my `QGraphicsView` blinking 1 second in red, 1 second in green and 1 second in blue and after that the loop start over again. After doing a lot of research in the past couple of days I didn't have a lot of luck as the main problem is that I am not sure I need to subclass `QGraphicsView` to obtain the effect I am looking for. I came across some references that I inserted below saying that for this type of problems `QPropertyAnimation` seems to be the right direction. Although setting a `QTimer` could also be a choice.

Below the small verifiable example. I wrote minimal code:

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QGraphicsView *mView;
    QGraphicsScene *mScene;
    QPropertyAnimation *mAnimation;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTimer>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    mView = new QGraphicsView();
    mScene = new QGraphicsScene();
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(mScene);
    // Starting with a gray background
    ui->graphicsView->setBackgroundBrush(QColor(Qt::gray));

    // Setting a timer that changes the color every second
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    timer->start(1000);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**mygraphicsview.h**

```
#ifndef MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H
#define MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H
#include <QGraphicsView>
class MyGraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
public:
    MyGraphicsView();
};

#endif // MYGRAPHICSVIEW_H
```

**mygraphicsview.cpp

```
#include "mygraphicsview.h"

MyGraphicsView::MyGraphicsView()
{}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

In case you would like to see the `.ui` I am also sharing the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>277</width>
    <height>228</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>277</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I have been researching the possibility to have a `QGraphicsView` blinking 1 second in red, 1 second in green and 1 second in blue and after that the loop start over again.

The only source I was able to find providing a complete example was in `PyQt`, for which I am not familiar with. The source is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50725166/blinking-buttons-in-pyqt5) and also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31786684/blinking-widget-with-pyqt).

The most important clue I got out of these examples is that, in particluar the last one, uses `QState` and `QStateMachine`. I am not familiar at all with these two features of `Qt` though and am struggling a little bit because of that.

Also I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975329/make-a-qlabel-blink) partial example, and the good thing of this is that I learned how to set the `QTimer` useful for the 1s interval blinking.

Also because I am dealing with a `QGraphicsView` I have the feeling that `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override` should be used.

Thank you very much for pointing in the right direction and solve this issue.

Comment: `QPropertyAnimation` is not a bad solution but you can't use it in this case because there is no `property` that allow to directly change the background color, you can use QPalette but it doesn't work with `QPropertyAnimation`, a possible solution is indeed to reimplement `paintEvent()` but there is many solution... with `QGraphicsScene`, with the `QGraphicsView` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QPropertyAnimation` is a problem here because the list of supported type is:

```cpp
Int, UInt, Double, Float, QLine, QLineF, QPoint
QPointF, QSize, QSizeF, QRect, QRectF, QColor
```

And if you look the available properties of the `QGraphicsView` class hierarchy

> `QWidget` [properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#properties)
>   `QFrame` [properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#properties)
>   `QAbstractScrollArea` [properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#properties)
>   `QGraphicsView` [properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#properties)

There is no interesting properties to pass to the `QPropertyAnimation` because `QPalette` and `QString` is not supported to play with `setPalette()` and `styleSheet()` and there is no variable to directly change the background color.

---

A solution is to subclass `QGraphicsView`:
**graphicsview.h**:

```cpp
#ifndef GRAPHICSVIEW_H
#define GRAPHICSVIEW_H

#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QTimer>

class GraphicsView : public QGraphicsView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GraphicsView(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *evt) override;

private slots:
    void changeBackgroundColor();

private:
    int color_index;
    QTimer timer;
    const QColor colors[3] = { Qt::red, Qt::green, Qt::blue };

};

#endif // GRAPHICSVIEW_H
```

**graphicsview.cpp**:

```cpp
#include "graphicsview.h"

GraphicsView::GraphicsView(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
{
    color_index = -1;
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(changeBackgroundColor()));
    timer.start(1000);
}

void GraphicsView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *evt)
{
    QGraphicsView::paintEvent(evt);

    QPainter painter(viewport());
    painter.fillRect(viewport()->rect(), colors[color_index]);
}

void GraphicsView::changeBackgroundColor()
{
    if (color_index == 2){
        color_index = 0;
    } else {
        color_index++;
    }
    viewport()->update(rect());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed explanation. I applied your suggestion at it works exactly as I wanted. I see also why you mentioned the `QPropertyAnmation` limitations. Thanks for your time! Very much appreciated!! :)