# How to maintain position of a QDialog on hide/show

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialog where I have a checkable button witch opens/close (hide/show) another window (the window is also a QDialog).

My problem is I wish to maintain the position of the second QDialog when I hide and after open it (Example: I move the QDialog in a corner of the screen and when I hide and then show it the QDialog needs to be in the same corner).

At this moment it seems to be restored at the initial position. I found a similar article about it at [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794532/how-to-make-a-qt-widget-invisible-without-changing-the-position-of-the-other-qt) but in my case I have two separate windows and I can move the second QDialog over the screen. Did anyone meet with this problem?

Comment: I cannot test it right now so can you try `setVisible(true)` instead of show?

Comment: I have all the mecanism except this property to stay in the same spot. This is the problem I can not find a solution.

Comment: @drescherjm it should do this though. It is defined that way: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#hide

Comment: You could possibly override `changeEvent(QEvent *event)` and save and restore the position when the dialog is hidden or shown.

Comment: @drescherjm well it's only with a Dialog or subclasses. not with widgets.

Comment: Is there any way to go around it? I can not change QDialog with QWidget.

Comment: That explains it. I mostly use widgets when I do similar because I don't need / want them to be modal.

Comment: Try overriding `showEvent`.

Comment: @student have you tried `setVisible(true)` instead of calliing `show`?

Comment: Yes. Same behavior.

Comment: @Hayt `show()` is actually calling `setVisible(true)`. See the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show)

Comment: @wasthishelpful yeah I was not sure though if there are some differences. But seeing that `QDialog` has overridden `showEvent` it is probably somewhere in there.

Comment: Years after this, I had the same problem and it turns out that indeed overriding the showEvent - just a dummy with no code in it - prevents the QDialog's showEvent to be called, which indeed explicitly centers the dialog over the parents window every time before it shows the dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK this works without any code: position isn't changed when showing/hiding a widget.

Anyway, you can store the position of your `QDialog` through its [geometry](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop):

```
// save geometry

QRect geometry = my_dialog->geometry();
my_dialog->hide();

// restore geometry

my_dialog->show();
my_dialog->setGeometry(geometry);
```

Note that the geometry is relative to the parent: I assume here your `QDialog` is modeless.

Comment: This seems to work fine. Apparently I can not override the setVisible function but I manage to make a function of my own that modifies this.